# Function to work out an average number of unique occurrences

Tags: r

I have the following code, which does what I want.  But I would like to know if there is a simpler/nicer way of getting there?

The overall aim of me doing this is that I am building a separate summary table for the overall data, so the average which comes out of this will go into that summary.

```
Test <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  Thing = c("Apple","Apple","Pear","Pear","Apple","Apple","Kiwi","Apple","Pear"),
  Day = c("Mon","Tue","Wed")
)

countfruit <- function(data){
df <- as.data.frame(table(data$ID,data$Thing))

df <- dcast(df, Var1 ~ Var2)
  colnames(df) = c("ID", "Apple","Kiwi", "Pear")

  #fixing the counts to apply a 1 for if there is any count there:
  df$Apple[df$Apple>0] = 1
  df$Kiwi[df$Kiwi>0] = 1
  df$Pear[df$Pear>0] = 1

  #making a new column in the summary table of how many for each person
  df$number <- rowSums(df[2:4])

return(mean(df$number))}

result <- countfruit(Test)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not quite get what you want to obtain with the code, can you expand a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you over complicate the problem, Here a small version keeping the same rationale.

```
df <- table(data$ID,data$Thing)
mean(rowSums(df>0))   ##  mean of non zero by column
```

**EDIT** one linear solution:

```
with(Test , mean(rowSums(table(ID,Thing)>0)))
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Yes I had a feeling I was overcomplicating, hence I thought I'd ask :)  thank you.  Any chance you could explain what 'with' does?  I had a look in the help file but can't decipher it :(

Comment: `with` Evaluate an R expression in an environment constructed from data, possibly modifying the original data. So within `with(Test , ...)` your data.frame Test becomes an environment, so no need to access variable using $, ID not Test$ID,.Go through the help, try the examples,no other way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to count how many nonzero entries in each column.  If so,  either use `as.logical` which will convert any nonzero number to `TRUE` (aka `1`) , or just count the number of zeros in a row and subtract from the number of pertinent columns.
For example, if I followed your code correctly, your dataframe is

```
  Var1 Apple Kiwi Pear
1    1     2    0    1
2    2     2    0    1
3    3     1    1    1
```

So, `(ncol(df)-1) - length(df[1,]==0)` gives you the count for the first row. 
Alternatively, use `as.logical` to convert all nonzero values to `TRUE` aka `1` and calculate the `rowSums`  over the columns of interest.

Comment: @Froom2  I agree w/ you.  I decided to write a mini-tutorial on ways to do things in `R` ;  agstudy has certainly written a clean solution.